# XGBoost's subsample = 0?

Tags: boosting, gradient, subsampling

In my use of XGBoost with the gradient-based method, I inadvertently set subsample to 0, yet it surprisingly returned a good result.

I am not sure how to explain it well. Any idea from the community?

Comment: Which XGBoost platform are you using? In R I get completely useless trees with `subsample=0`

Comment: I use Python XGBoost's sklearn interface. For some reasons it worked well in my case and I don't know why and have no idea how to explain it.